# Highlight control in a disabled form using reflection in VB.Net for any selected Assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am using Reflection with VB.Net to get all the forms in a list box and all controls in another list box for the selected form in the first list box for any selected Assembly from any location.

On selection of any form and clicking the 'Open Form' button it opens that particular form in disable state.

But it throws exception as connection could not established(seems the load event of the form still fires which is not desired).

So now i want that the form should load in disable state without firing any event of it and also if any of the control will be selected then it will be highlighted in the form with a red border.

Can any one help me in this regard ?

Comment: You cannot prevent the Load event from firing.  I would have to recommend you pursue a more practical and usable UI, creating disabled windows doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do not open the form. Just create it, and then you can loop through the Controls collection.

```
Dim frm = New Form1()
For Each ctl As Control In frm.Controls
    Console.WriteLine(ctl.Name)
Next
```

---

EDIT:

In order to be able to open a form without executing its Form Load event handler, add this code to the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Enabled Then
        ' Put your loading code here
        MsgBox("Form_Load")
    End If
End Sub
```

I do not know if it is possible to do that in your case; however, I do not see another possibility.

---

Now to the controller form. We use a button as red border, since it is possible to change its border appearance. We cannot make it transparent. Therefore, we will send it to the background and make it a little bit larger than the control it is supposed to mark.

```
Dim frm As Form
Dim redBorder As Button

Private Sub ControllerForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Create another form.
    ' (You would do that with Reflection after selecting a form name from a listbox)
    frm = New FormWithControls()

    ' Get the control names and fill the controls listbox
    For Each ctrl As Control In frm.Controls
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ctrl.Name)
    Next

    'Disable and display the form
    frm.Enabled = False
    frm.Show()

    'Create a red border and add it to the other form
    redBorder = New Button()
    redBorder.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    redBorder.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2
    redBorder.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
    frm.Controls.Add(redBorder)
    redBorder.SendToBack()
    redBorder.Visible = False

    ' Get the focus back to this form
    Me.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Get the selected control
    Dim ctrl = frm.Controls(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())

    ' Position and size the red border
    Dim rect = ctrl.Bounds
    rect.Inflate(2, 2)
    redBorder.Bounds = rect
    redBorder.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is to show the particular for and when i will try to select the particular control name in the listbox list it should highlight that particular control in the new form bny putting a red border around it....

Answer (score 0):

When opening form use

```
Dim f1 as new [Form name]
```

Ex:

```
Dim f1 as new Form1
```